# Using $in and $lt to find data with specific array values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a people collection with a timeline array containing a year when something happened to this person. For example the year they were born, like this:

```
db.people.insert({
  "timeline": [
    { "born_year": 1999 },
    { "other_event": 2005 }
  ]
});
```

I can query this collection for someone born 1999:

```
db.people.find({
  "timeline": { $in: [ { "born_year": 1999 } ] }
});
```

However, when using $lt to query for people born before 2000 I don't get any results at all:

```
db.people.find({
  "timeline": { $in: [ { "born_year": { $lt: 2000 } } ] }
});
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using dot notation to target specific element properties rather than matching entire elements as objects:

```js
db.people.find({
  "timeline.born_year": { $lt: 2000 }
});
```

This will find all docs that have a `timeline` array element with a property of `born_year` with a value < 2000.

For the exact comparison:

```js
db.people.find({
  "timeline.born_year": 1999
});
```

Comment: This would require a minor structure change to the objects, but it would be a wise change.

Comment: Btw, Brandon what kind of structure change would be wise to use and why? I'm just starting to learn MongoDB so all tips are welcome :)